# Incorrect code syntax (scrollbar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I'm trying to implement [this scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) and would like to change the scroll inertia but looks like I made a syntax error in the code below. Would you know what the error is?
Many thanks

```
<script>
    (function($){
        $(window).load(function(){
            $(".content_2").mCustomScrollbar()
            scrollInertia:150
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(window).load(function(){
     $(".content_2").mCustomScrollbar({
          scrollInertia:150
     });      
 });
```

You should see examples here for proper usage -

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$(".content_2").mCustomScrollbar()
scrollInertia:150
```

by

```
$(".content_2").mCustomScrollbar({
   scrollInertia:150
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing in the data but trying to define an object somehow.

```
$(".content_2").mCustomScrollbar({
            scrollInertia:150
});
```